# Populating Array in Swift 4 with for-loop without using the index

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, for-loop

I need to populate an Array (already declared and initialized) using a for loop in order to create a determinate amount of items.

I ended up with the following code:

```
    func createValues() -> Array<Int> {

        let usableRange:Range = 6..<11;

        var arrayOfValues: Array<Int>=[]; //Array declared and initialized

        for i in 0..<10 {

            arrayOfValues.append(random(usableRange));

            print(arrayOfValues[i]);

        }

        return arrayOfValues;
    }
```

this code does what I expect it to do just fine. However, as soon as I comment out the line

```
 print(arrayOfValues[i]);
```

Xcode throws the following warning:

> Immutable value 'i' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or
>   removing it

If I accept the suggestion the code works, but not as fine as it did before.

I'm just transitioning from Obj-C to Swift and I don't really know what the proper way to do this should be. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm aware that I don't need semicolons anymore, but old habits die hard, I guess...

Comment: "not as fine as it did before." Why not? The only difference is that it doesn't print anything

Comment: Please learn to read and understand error / warning messages. This is one of the most comprehensible.

Comment: well, by the press of a button, the code should generate random numbers between a range. If the average of the given numbers is not the average of the range it generates new numbers until it does. This is all fine, but when I replace the 'i' for a _, I have to press the button many times until I have something printed on the console. I'm debugging it right now to see where the problem can be...

Comment: @vadian I understand the warning just fine. The question is how to do what I want to do in a proper warning-free way

Comment: As Leo already mentioned the code does exactly the same (creating 10 random numbers) except it does not print anything in the loop.

Comment: "when I replace the 'i' for a _, I have to press the button many times" What button do you have to press many times?

Comment: @CraigGrummitt the button I press to initiate the action

Comment: you could write print(arrayOfValues.last) instead

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't use i, you can just write

```
for _ in 0 ..< 10
```

The _ means "yes, there is a value, but I don't care about it", here and in many other situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a good alternative for your code, I'm offering you this:

```
var i: Int = 0

while i < 10 {

  arrayOfValues.append(random(usableRange))
  i += 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to generate an array of random numbers in your given range, I would suggest you simply generate it directly. There is no need for the `for` loop.

```
let usableRange = UInt32(6)..<UInt32(11)
let arr = (0..<10).map { _ in Int(
    arc4random_uniform(usableRange.upperBound - usableRange.lowerBound) 
    + usableRange.lowerBound
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array` has a designated initalizer, which initalizes an array with a given size and a repeated value:

```
let values = Array(repeating: "VALUE", count: 5)
print(fiveZs)
// Prints "["VALUE", "VALUE", "VALUE", "VALUE", "VALUE"]"
```

Source: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init)